# Best practice for handling Long I/O operation inside Express request

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, asynchronous, request

Seeking input regarding the best pattern for handling a long I/O operation inside an Express request handler. Specifically, I'll be copying an uploaded file to S3, but don't need for the I/O to complete to finish handling the request. (Note: need to have a local copy on the server so uploading directly to S3 is not a solution.)

I have a working solution that copies the file asynchronously to S3, but it doesn't wait on the copy to complete before returning from the request. There are no *apparent* issues with this solution. However, the approach seems flawed and there is probably a better pattern (I am relatively new to JS).

I can alternatively queue the copy task and handle in the background. But before adding more code, checking to see if my concerns are valid or if no issues with how implemented as-is.

Any insights appreciated.

Edit: added sample code showing pattern

```
/* Async handler because await on some other (not related to S3 copy)stuff to complete before returning (but must faster completion than the S3 copy */
app.get("/some/route", async (req, res) => {
    
    s3.upload(/* args */).then(() => {
        // log success
    }).catch((e) => {
        // log error
    })

    // A few lines of code
    res.status(200).send('Done');
    // We be done before s3.upload completes
});
```

Comment: FWIW, if there are other places in the code using `await`, it's best to be consistent and use `await` (and `try`/`catch`) with the call to `s3.upload` as well. Also, when passing an `async` function to something like `app.get` that won't do anything with the promise it returns, it's important not to let the function ever reject its promise, for instance by putting `try`/`catch` around the entire function body. Node.js currently handles unhandled rejections with a warning that it may in future versions terminate the process when they're detected, which wouldn't be good. :-)

Comment: Example: https://pastebin.com/RuJk2eL1

Comment: What your code is currently doing is handle the copy task in the background and queuing  the completion of that task - exactly what you propose to do but all handled for you by the interpreter. This is what the event loop is for but without extra cruft added to the code to obscure your intention which is to save the file and return immediately without waiting.

Comment: @slebetman, thanks for confirming as-is pattern is OK. I figured it was getting added to event queue that node waits on for all promises to complete, but pattern "felt" wrong nonetheless. Regarding call to S3, intentionally not awaiting on it because don't want to block on I/O to complete, which is crux of the question asked.

Answer (score 2):

Your approach for uploading files (resources) is perfectly fine regarding the situation.

I would recommend the following to improve usability for the future :

1. On the upload request generate a UUID for the resources and return that to the user (this UUID will allow the user to manage the resources). Use `202 Accepted` for the response status code.
2. Add API to query the state of the resources. This will return information on the state of the resources like `uploading` | `done` | `not_exsist`
3. (Nice to have) Add API to abort the upload
4. (Nice to have) Add WebSocket that can notify a client about the state of the resources.